# What is the default user mapping for a server role in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am learning the relations among authentication-user-role-schema. In my application I am using my Windows authentication which is assigned as sysadmin(as well as public) server role.

After that, when I am executing `SELECT CURRENT_USER`, I get `dbo`. However, I can't find the mapping from the server role to the database user. I also tested by creating a login which has the server role as public. Using this login, I got guest when I executed `SELECT CURRENT_USER`.

So where does this mapping get defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to check the mapping, and what is the part confusing me. Firstly, the query to check the mapping between server login and the db user is something like this:

```
SELECT
SDP.PRINCIPAL_ID AS [Principal ID], 
SDP.NAME AS [Database UserName], 
SDP.TYPE_DESC AS [Datebase UserType],  
SSP.NAME AS [Server LoginName], 
SSP.TYPE_DESC AS [Server LoginType]
FROM sys.database_principals SDP 
INNER JOIN sys.server_principals SSP 
ON SDP.sid = SSP.sid
```

the sid is the unique identifier for all the principals including server level, db level.

Secondly, the actual part which confused me it. It is because there is an implicit mapping and yet it won't be shown even by the query. Let me describe my question again: I use my Windows login (let's call it MY_W_NAME) as the authentication mode to log into SQL Server. And after that, when I execute select CURRENT_USER to one database, I get dbo, which is a database user. It's only nature that I would assume there is an explicit mapping between MY_W_NAME and dbo and I want to find that. I am using SQL Server management studio and I see in the properties window of my the server login MY_W_NAME, there is one tab called User Mapping. So I was expecting to see a mapping here, only to find there is none. After I run the query above, I still can't find MY_W_NAME listed there. so it is really mysterious how it is mapped.

It turned out it is because MY_W_NAME is of server role 'sysadmin', and by default this login will be mapped into all 'dbo' database user for all the databases. But this mapping won't be displayed by the query, nor on the user mapping tab in the properties window. Some further experiments show more interest facts: I actually can add a explicit mapping from MY_W_NAME to a specific database, for example, from script or from the properties window. However, even though I see the execution of creating a new DB user for MY_W_NAME is successful, when I run select CURRENT_USER to this DB, I still get dbo. I guess it is because 'sysadmin' really has higher privilege. On the contrary, if I created a server login with 'public' server role, and I add a mapping between this login to a DB user, this mapping will be displayed.

I must say this is not a natural way to a normal human-being with limited experience in SQL Server. After a couple of days, finally someone pointed it out to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not real sure what you're asking.

Your user login must have the `sysadmin` role.  Internally, all users with the `sysadmin` role will automatically impersonate the `dbo` user.  This is how the `sysadmin` role works.  If you add another user login and run `SELECT CURRENT_USER()`, you will get the actual user's name instead of `dbo`.

As far as where the mapping in general is defined, it's in the `sys.server_principals` and `sys.server_role_members` system catalogs.  You can use this query to see the mappings:

```
select      r.name "role_name", m.name "member_name"
from        sys.server_principals r
left join   (sys.server_role_members rm
            inner join  sys.server_principals m
                        on rm.member_principal_id = m.principal_id)
            on r.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id
where       r.type = 'R'
order by    r.name, m.name
```

You must use the stored procedures `sp_addsrvrolemember` and `sp_dropsrvrolemember` to actually modify the mappings.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted to do. And the confusing part is the user of sysadmin role will not be explicitly shown in the result of the query I described in my own answer. So I was like "what the what? Why the inner join doesn't show my (sysadmin) login mapping to dbo by my query but CURRENT_USER returns it(dbo)?"

Comment: @tete Don't confuse the `dbo` user account with the `db_owner` fixed role. If your server login is a member of `sysadmin` server role, then you will automatically map to the `dbo` user account, which is a built-in user account with implied access to do anything to a DB. It's not a role mapping. It's essentially user impersonation.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669065.aspx

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not totally sure of your question, you might want to check out [`IS_SRVROLEMEMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176015%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), for example:

```
select is_srvrolemember('sysadmin');
select is_srvrolemember('dbcreator');
select is_srvrolemember('bulkadmin');
select is_srvrolemember('diskadmin');
select is_srvrolemember('processadmin');
select is_srvrolemember('serveradmin');
select is_srvrolemember('setupadmin');
select is_srvrolemember('securityadmin');
```

or perhaps even

```
select is_member('dbo');
select is_member('public');
select is_member('guest');
```

There are a bunch of [security functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186236%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) in SQL Server 2008 that may help you.

Comment: I am sorry but that's probably not what I meant. I want to ask how I get the 'dbo', which I assume is the database user 'dbo', from my login using my Windows login, which from what I can see, is only assigned a 'sysadmin' server role. Because I can't find a clear mapping path between these two. Plus, I am really confused by your second script. I see that the function is_member requires either Windows group or SQL Server role name. However, I can't find 'dbo' and 'guest' listed in my server role. I am pretty sure this function works so I must have some misunderstanding